# php pdo, refactor wild card statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I was wondering how I could refactor this code it doesn't seem to be the best way of pulling each result for every letter (A-Z).

I was thinking of a `foreach` statement for example, `foreach %a, %b` etc.. query the database.

```
$categoryA = query('SELECT * FROM category WHERE category LIKE "A%"',
  array('category' => ['category']),
  $conn);

$categoryB = query('SELECT * FROM category WHERE category LIKE "B%"',
  array('category' => ['category']),
  $conn);
```

This is my function

```
function query($query, $bindings, $conn)
{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($bindings);
    return $stmt;
}
```

Comment: I don't get it, really. The `$bindings` parameter seems to be completely useless. You could also simply fetch *all* categories in one query without `WHERE` clause and split them into different arrays in PHP easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression instead of LIKE in order to do this.  Change your query into:

```
SELECT * FROM category WHERE category REGEXP "^[A-Z].*"
```

A further explanation: The regular expression ^[A-Z].* means any string that starts with a letter from A to Z, followed by any number of characters.

I would note that this form of a query, though more elegant looking than a bunch of LIKE queries, isn't very fast since it will NOT use indexes.  That means that you should only use it if you know that there aren't a lot of rows to scan or that you will be returning most of the rows in the table.  If neither of these conditions exist, you are better off concatenating LIKE statements as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM category WHERE (category LIKE "A%" OR category LIKE "B%" OR ... )
```

This latter form will use an index on the category field if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, you do not want to write 26 times (for 26 characters) almost the code. Which is good, because that would be the opposite of [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).

You could try it like this:

```
$categories = array();

for($i = ord('A'); $i <= ord('Z'); $i++) {
    $char = chr($i);        
    $categories[$char] = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM category WHERE category LIKE "'.$char.'%"')->fetchAll();
}
```

You would then have an associative array with the 26 letters as keys and your categories as value.

Your query function sadly won't do the job for you, because it will only return true (on success) or false (on failure).

Performance: You would still execute 26 queries. It's not the most performant solution, but I guess it's pretty straight forward to understand.

And also:

> Premature optimization is the root of all evil

(Donald Knuth)

So, if you are learning at the moment, just try if it works for you and don't worry too much about the number of queries right now.